# jdbc ResultSet closed

Tags: java, jdbc

I have following source.

In insertMessage(..), it calls selectMessage to check whether duplicate record exists or not.

But this error occurs.
In my brain, it works fine because datasource gives me new Connection...maybe

```
java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet closed
    at org.sqlite.RS.checkOpen(RS.java:63)
    at org.sqlite.RS.findColumn(RS.java:108)
    at org.sqlite.RS.getString(RS.java:317)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getString(DelegatingResultSet.java:263)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getString(DelegatingResultSet.java:263)
    at org.springframework.context.support.CachedMessageSourceDao.selectMessage(CachedMessageSourceDao.java:68)
    at org.springframework.context.support.CachedMessageSourceDao.insertMessage(CachedMessageSourceDao.java:94)
    at MessageSourceDemo.main(MessageSourceDemo.java:11)
```

---

```
public String selectMessage(String code, String language) {
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String value = null;

    String sql = "SELECT code, value, language FROM " + TABLE + " where code=? and language=? and flag = '" + FLAG_OK + "'";

    try {
        conn = dataSource.getConnection();
        conn.setAutoCommit(true);
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.setString(1, code);
        pstmt.setString(2, language);
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        rs.next();

        String _code = rs.getString("code");
        String _value = rs.getString("value");
        String _language = rs.getString("language");
        Locale _locale = new Locale(_language);
        value = _value;

    } catch(SQLException ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();

    } finally {

        try {
            if(rs != null);
            if(pstmt != null) pstmt.close();
            if(conn != null) conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    return value;
}

public synchronized void insertMessage(String code, String value, String language) throws SQLException {
    //Duplicate Message Check
    **if(selectMessage(code, language) != null) throw new SQLException("Duplicate message exists for code: " + code + " and" + "language: " + language);**

    String sql = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE + " (code, value, language, flag) values (?, ?, ?, '" + FLAG_OK + "')";

    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

    try {
        conn = dataSource.getConnection();
        conn.setAutoCommit(true);
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.setString(1, code);
        pstmt.setString(2, value);
        pstmt.setString(3, language);
        pstmt.execute();

    } catch(SQLException ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();

    } finally {

        try {

            if(pstmt != null) pstmt.close();
            if(conn != null) conn.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    notifyMessageChange(); //Realtime apply to MessageSource
}
```

Comment: Can you point to line in your code which is throwing exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `resultset` probably didn't have any record, which is the reason why `next()` closed it.

[next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()) returns a boolean, check it.

Answer (score 2):

Check the value of `rs.next();` It must be returning false. You need to do this.

```
   if(rs.next()){
       //get data

   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check what `rs.next` returns. If it is `false` means nothing was fetched.

Now if you use `if(rs.next)` then you are considering only the 1st row that the `ResultSet` has returned. If the query returns more than 1 rows and you want to consider all the rows then use `while(rs.next)`.

Again even if you add `while(rs.next)` above your code then the `_code, _value, _language _locale` would have the values of the last row returned in the `ResultSet`. So you have to modify your code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot only add `rs.next()` because `ResultSet` can be empty so you have to add condition and tests if result of `next()` is valid row, else it returns false.

```
conn = dataSource.getConnection();
        conn.setAutoCommit(true);
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.setString(1, code);
        pstmt.setString(2, language);
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next())

        String _code = rs.getString("code");
        String _value = rs.getString("value");
        String _language = rs.getString("language");
        Locale _locale = new Locale(_language);
        value = _value;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In place of this -

```
rs.next();
String _code = rs.getString("code");
String _value = rs.getString("value");
String _language = rs.getString("language");
```

Use this -

```
while(rs.next()) //or use if(if there is only one row in resultset)
{
    String _code = rs.getString("code");
    String _value = rs.getString("value");
    String _language = rs.getString("language"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer this [page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29).

```
public boolean next()
                 throws SQLException
    Moves the cursor down one row from its current position. A ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the first call to the method next makes the first row the current row; the second call makes the second row the current row, and so on.
    ***If an input stream is open for the current row, a call to the method next will implicitly close it.*** A ResultSet object's warning chain is cleared when a new row is read.

    Returns:
    true if the new current row is valid; false if there are no more rows
    Throws:
    SQLException - if a database access error occurs
```