# How can I keep the resultSet open, or make calls to different resultSets?

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc

I am running queries on 2 separate databases in the same .java file, using JDBC and SQLite, but I am getting an error that the Result Set is closed when I try to make my second call to a separate result set.  I set up the connections and everything and then do 3 separate calls, like this....followed by calls to the `ResultSet` objects to get data.  I get an error on the first call to `mealSet`

```
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn1 = null;
        conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:workoutLog.db");
        @SuppressWarnings("null")
        PreparedStatement workoutQuery= conn1.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM workoutLog");// ORDER BY t desc limit 1");
        ResultSet workoutSet = workoutQuery.executeQuery();


        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn2 = null;
        conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:foodLog.db");
        PreparedStatement getFoodLog = conn2.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM foodLog");// ORDER BY t desc limit 3");
        ResultSet mealSet = getFoodLog.executeQuery();
        mealSet.next();

        meals.add(breakfast);
        meals.add(lunch);
        meals.add(dinner);

        weekStart = workoutSet.getInt(ID_COLUMN);
        weekEnd = weekEnd + 6;
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn3 = null;
        conn3 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:projectLog.db");
        PreparedStatement getProjectLog = conn3.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM projectLog");
        ResultSet projectSet = getProjectLog.executeQuery();
        ResultSetMetaData meta = projectSet.getMetaData();


        for (int i=3;i<meta.getColumnCount()-1;i++){
            String prj="";
            projects.add(prj);
        }


        while ( projectSet.next()){

            for (int i=3;i<=meta.getColumnCount()-1;i++){
                int arrayPos = 0;
                String temp =projectSet.getString(i) + "\n";
                projects.set(arrayPos, projects.get(arrayPos).concat(temp));
                projectNames.add(meta.getColumnName(i));
                totalHours+=projectSet.getInt(3);
                totalMinutes+=projectSet.getInt(meta.getColumnCount());
                arrayPos++;
            }


            for (int k=0;k<=2;k++){
            breakfast=mealSet.getString(BREAKFAST_COLUMN)+" \n";
            lunch=mealSet.getString(LUNCH_COLUMN)+" \n"; 
            dinner=mealSet.getString(DINNER_COLUMN)+" \n";
            meals.set(0, meals.get(0).concat(breakfast));
            meals.set(1, meals.get(1).concat(lunch));
            meals.set(2, meals.get(2).concat(dinner));
            mealSet.next(); 
        }
```

error being...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet closed
    at org.sqlite.RS.checkOpen(RS.java:63)
    at org.sqlite.RS.markCol(RS.java:77)
    at org.sqlite.RS.getString(RS.java:313)
    at WeeklyReport.main(WeeklyReport.java:99)
```

Comment: Post enough code for us to see the whole picture and also post the exact error with traceback (if available).

Comment: EDITED: added more code and the error trace

Comment: Have a look at this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977064/jdbc-resultset-closed

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reuse the same `ResultSet` instance for numerous queries. One `ResultSet` instance can only be used only to fetch the results of one query.

Moreover as written in the [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) JavaDoc:

> `ResultSet` object is automatically closed when the `Statement` object that generated it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results.

Comment: But I'm getting this error even though I am not using the same `ResultSet` instance...I am purposely creating multiple instances for each set of calls.

Comment: And what happens with your Statements? Maybe you can paste the whole code of your application?